# Get a sequence of multiples of an integer between two values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sequence

OK the title is ugly but the problem is quite straightforward:

I have a WPF control where I want to display plot lines. My "viewport" has its limits, and these limits (for example, bottom and top value in object coordinates) are `doubles`.

So I would like to draw lines at every multiple of, say, 5. If my viewport goes from -8.3 to 22.8, I would get `[-5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20]`.

I would like to use LINQ, it seems the natural candidate, but cannot find a way...

I imagine something along these lines:

```
int nlines = (int)((upper_value - lower_value)/step);
var seq = Enumerable.Range((int)(Math.Ceiling(magic_number)), nlines).Select(what_else);
```

Given values are `(double)lower_value`, `(double)upper_value` and `(int)step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
double lower_value = -8.3;
double upper_value = 22.8;
int step = 5;

int low = (int)lower_value / step;
int up = (int)upper_value / step;

var tt = Enumerable.Range(low, up - low + 1).Select(i => i * step);
```

**EDIT**
This code is intended for all negative values of the `lower_value` and for positive values which are divisible by the `step`. To make it work for all other positive values as well, the following correction should be applied:

```
if (lower_value > step * low)
    low++;
```

Comment: that is an inside-out version of @paqogomez answer, avoiding the post-generation test by doing the downscaling by step beforehand. Gonna give it a try and give you some feedback very soon. Thanks.

Comment: This still enumerates every number in the range.

Comment: @LordTakkera No. The `Enumerable.Range` returns as many values as desired in the result.

Comment: @LordTakkera the difference is that the range is already smaller, given the pre-linq division of `low` and `up` by `step`.

Answer (score 8):

Enumerable.Range should do the trick:

```
Enumerable.Range(lower_value, upper_value - lower_value)
          .Where(x => x % step == 0);
```

Comment: Just beat me to it! Note that you need to cast lower/upper value to ints first (Math.Floor with a cast would be even better)

Comment: `Range` second argument seems to be "count", not "upper value", is it?

Comment: This only works for integer sized steps, and is super inefficient for large step values.  It is also only valid for ranges less than `int.MaxValue` in size, and entirely in the range of `int.MinValue` to `int.MaxValue`, which is much more restrictive than the range of a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is to determine the nearest factor of your step value from your starting point.  Some simple arithmetic can deduce this value:

```
public static double RoundToMultiple(double value, double multiple)
{
    return value - value % multiple;
}
```

To then create a sequence of all factors of a given value between a range an iterator block is well suited:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> FactorsInRange(
    double start, double end, double factor)
{
    var current  = RoundToMultiple(start, factor);
    while (start < end)
    {
        yield return start;
        current = current + factor;
    }
}
```

If you have the [Generate method from MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Generate.cs?r=700d335046d2e00f3b9cd9e602db00a9f090d5bc), then you could write this without an explicit iterator block:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> FactorsInRange(
    double start, double end, double factor)
{
    return Generate(RoundToMultiple(start, factor),
        current => current + factor)
        .TakeWhile(current => current < end);
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful, but can you think (sorry for even asking) of a sort of "one liner" version of this?

Comment: @heltonbiker I wouldn't want to do so even if I could.  I consider this the most well designed solution of this problem, in such a way that it is both correct and most easily understood, maintained, and improved on.  If you started with something like a `Generate` method from MoreLinq then the additional code could shrink.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to enumerate *every* number, you'll have to go outside of LINQ:

```
List<int> steps;
int currentStep = (lower_value / step) * step; //This takes advantage of integer division to "floor" the factor
steps.Add(currentStep);
while (currentStep < upper_value)
{
   currentStep += step;
   steps.Add(currentStep);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to the code.

```
    private List<int> getMultiples(double lower_value, double upper_value, int step) {
        List<int> steps = new List<int>();
        int currentStep = (int)(lower_value / step) * step; //This takes advantage of integer division to "floor" the factor
        steps.Add(currentStep);
        while (currentStep <= upper_value) {
            steps.Add(currentStep);
            currentStep += step;
        }
        return steps;
    }
```